# Laravel - How to load content with new URL

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have inherited a Laravel project to which I need to add a new page with some functionality that I have created. What I've got appears to be a main "app.blade.php" file, which includes some stuff that will always be visible.. like sidebar, login auth stuff and so on.

Now adding stuff to this is no problem. But what I want is a separate .php file that is loaded in the main content area of the app.blade.php when I go to a certain URL, let's call it "mypage.com/newpage". (Essentially, I want a link in  the sidebar to load this new content.)

So my custom content should appear in the main content area, but the standard sidebar, etc, should still be there. I'm guessing it's something with routes, but... How do I proceed? Which files do I edit? What do I add and where? I already got my new HTML and Javascript code ready - I simply need to add it into the Laravel project the right way.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#extending-a-layout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose , bellow code is your app.blade.php file which you want to inherit.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @section('sidebar')
            This is the master sidebar.
        @show

        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and you want to load the app.blade.php file here. You need to extends the page and declare the sections like this.

```
@extends('app')

@section('title', 'Page Title')

@section('sidebar')
    @parent

    <p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@endsection

@section('content')
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@endsection
```

[Extending a layout on laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#extending-a-layout) This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is template inheritance. You create a layout template that you use as the main layout and your pages inherit that main layout template. See the Laravel Blade documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#template-inheritance